# "Successfull"/"successful" — is this a UK/US difference?

Tags: british-english, orthography, dialects, doubled-consonants

I would tend to write double-l, but Google gives me more single-l, so I'm guessing it's an Atlantic divide thing.

And I guess all the other *full words.

Comment: There seems to be a trend of "Is X/Y a British English/American English difference?" questions where X is a word, and Y is a typo.

Comment: (I removed the "single-word-request" tag, because it doesn't seem to apply.)

Comment: @Seamus: This question reverses the trend, in this case X is a typo

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I would say *successfull* is a typo. Neither [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/successfull) nor [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/successfull) mention it as an alternative spelling. The British National Corpus has [10695 cites for *successful*](http://bnc.bl.uk/saraWeb.php?qy=successful&mysubmit=Go) and exactly one for *successfull*. According to OneLook, [33 dictionaries](http://www.onelook.com/?w=successful&ls=a) have an entry for *successful*, but only Wordnik has a [few cites](http://www.wordnik.com/words/successfull) for *successfull* (without a definition).

**Edit:** by popular request, I will add that the adverb *successfully* is written with two L's. *Successfuly* would be incorrect.

Comment: Yes, "successfully" is correct, but "successfull" is not. And OneLook seems to be a very nice resource for us here (+1 for that link too)

Answer (score 39):

Only *full* is spelled with two Ls. All other *-ful* words are spelled with only one L: *helpful, successful, skillful, beautiful*.

Comment: To add an especially interesting case: *chock full* vs *chock-full* vs *chockful*.

Comment: However, *skillful* vs *skilful* is a difference between en-us and en-gb. And *full* undoubles the l when used as a prefix too, as in e.g. *fulsome* and *fulfil*.

Comment: Interesting. If you fill a sock with pennies, do you have a *sockful* or a *sockfull*?